# Xcode deleted image keeps coming back

Tags: xcode

I replaced my image set that corresponds to the UIImageView image in my LaunchScreen.storyboard, but it keeps showing up.

I've deleted the old image set, emptied the trash, cleaned the build folder, redid the whole storyboard, but it KEEPS COMING BACK!!!!

Comment: Did you try reinstalling the app on the device / Resetting the simulator? The launch screen is rendered by the system and not your app so maybe this helps. Also, are you sure there is no image in your assets configured as a launch image?

Comment: I completely reinstalled the app on my iPhone 6s to no avail. What do you mean "launch image?"

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so the launch images are apparently cached.

I had to delete the app completely, restart the phone and then reinstall.